# Can I update multiple aggregate instances of the same type in one transaction?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Sorry if it's duplicated, I have searched a lot in SO, but I didn't find a matched question.

I know we shouldn't update multiple aggregate instances in one transaction. However, I think the "multiple aggregate instances" here means multiple instance of different aggregate types. Am I right?

Say, **Product** and **BacklogItem** are two different aggregates, so we should avoid updating both Product and BacklogItem in one single transaction.

But what if I need to update multiple instances of the *same aggregate type*? Say, I need to update all **products**' name. What's the best way to deal with it?

**pseudocode**

```
//Application Service
public void ChangeTitle(string newName)
{
    using(uow.BeginTransaction())
    {
         IEnumerable<Product> products = repo.GetAll();
         foreach(var product in products)
         {
             product.ChangeName(newName);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can not. If you need to do this then your Aggregate's boundaries are wrong.

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Not necessarily. There are cases where it may be acceptable to violate the rule and trade scalability for strong consistency.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The type of AR is irrelevant, ARs are always transactional boundaries. When working with many of them you should usually embrace partial failures and eventual consistency.

Why should all renames fail or succeed if there are no invariants to protect across all these ARs. For instance, if the UI did allow users to rename multiple products at a time and some user renames hundreds of them. If one product failed to be renamed because of a concurrency conflict for instance, would it be better not to rename any of the products or inform the user that one of them failed?

You can always violate the rule, but you must understand that the more ARs that are involved in a transaction, the more likely you are to experience transactional failures due to concurrency conflicts (assuming contention can occur).

I usually only modify multiple ARs in one transaction when there are invariants crossing ARs boundaries and I can't afford to avoid dealing with eventual consistency.

Comment: Old, but best post I've ever read on this subject. What if you don't care about scalability, concurrency problems, have invariants crossing AR and need an immediate consistency across aggregates, additionally don't have a skill and time to create a complex infrustructure to ensure eventual consistency, but want to learn or create an app - which just "works" - you can always refactor, extend it later which makes the challenge more interesting and real-life (I guess), instead of striving for perfection for the first time.

Comment: @darius1 I support that. KISS would be the main driver here and I've often modified many ARs in a single transaction for the reasons you mentioned. However, you shouldn't find yourself having to modify multiple ARs in a single tx very often or in all use cases involving that AR.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the guidance is related to expectations of concurrent access.  Depending on how many users you have accessing your system at one time, the more things that change in a single transaction, the more risk of concurrent changes, which will either:

- cause errors or exceptions due to concurrency violations if you use optimistic concurrency management
- cause delays due to locking if you use pessimistic concurrency management
- cause data consistency issues if you use no concurrency management

This guidance applies whether the size of the things that is changing gets broader (changing more types of aggregates) or deeper (changing more instances of the same aggregate).  Rather than considering exactly what is changing, consider, what is the risk that some parts of this change will conflict with a similar change being made by another person at the same time?

Designing DDD for highly concurrent multi-user systems is where the guidance to design small independent aggregates comes from.  If that is not your case, then you can potentially violate the guidance based on the your own risk analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregates are used to guard transactional boundaries. From what I see in your pseudocode you are changing them all in one transaction.

Is there any reason that it should be done in one transaction? if so, then it seems like you are missing a concept in your model. This concept could be nothing more then a simple process manager which updates multiple aggregates in your domain and report back when everything finished successfully, it could even incorporate some retry mechanisms or other exception handling in case of a failure in one of the updates. This process manager could be named 'bulk renamer' or something like that?

I would model such a bulk renamer in such a way that it registers itself as a consumer of all domain events from the aggregates that need to be updated, then updates the name of those aggregates (potentially in parallel) and then keeps listening for the domain events. When all events are received it could report back that it finished renaming all aggregates, and perform exception handling.

Answer (score -2):

why always talk about concurrency risk ， this kind of operation always exist in erp or other like erp.

there are many operations like batch add resources.

why ddd bound must build on one aggregateroot ，not multiple same type aggregate roots such us one “domain”，which handle multiple same type aggregate roots .

or wheather there is a bound type beyond aggregateroots

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).